# Resizing Images To Match Photo Frame width and height

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website that has two types of images

- Portrait photos

[image]

- Landscape photos

[image]

Like you can see i have two types :

- square
- rectangular

I have to resize all the photo in this page :

http://freche.epartenaire.com/materiel-de-location-21_%C3%89l%C3%A9vation_Travaux-en-hauteur_NACELLE-PL.php

Square and rectangular to fit into squares in here

[image]

sow if image is square or rectangular it doesn't matter it has to fit into squere

can you please give me some advice (plugins or techniques)

I'm using php jquery javascript

I am grateful for every advice

Comment: you can set a defined height and width from css

Comment: Let's assume that he doesn't want 2Mb pictures displaying on his site unoptimized.

Comment: Make a `div` that is the same `height` and `width` place the image inside set the `width: 100%`. Tell your `div` to be `overflow:hidden;` then they will all look the same shape and size, nice and tidy :)

Comment: Honestly, images that are out of proportion are really ugly and look unprofessional. I'd rather keep them as they are and center them on a slightly darker background color (to separate them from the websites background color) and use real thumbnails instead of just a css solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
div{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But the preceding code will cause the image to be stretched. So, you may use background image instead of image element. And you can use `background-size: cover;background-position: center;`

---

But still if you want to use image element instead of background-image, there are a lot of plugins. I like the below plugin much.

https://github.com/levymetal/jquery-resize-image-to-parent

```
$('.my-image').resizeToParent();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP to do this.

There are two libraries that jump out, either Imagick or GD.

There are then additional libraries that wrap Imagick, such as :

http://image.intervention.io/

You can start with installing Imagick on your server if you don't already have it. (Check phpinfo first)

Using a package manager:

`sudo apt-get install php5-imagick`

Once it's installed, you can then thumbnail an image quite easily:

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php

Sample code goes like this:

```
<?php
/* Read the image */
$im = new imagick( "test.png" );
/* create the thumbnail */
$im->cropThumbnailImage( 80, 80 );
/* Write to a file */
$im->writeImage( "th_80x80_test.png" );
?>
```

Personally, however, I might ignore all of this, and just jump straight into a SaaS that provides this functionality to you.

For example: http://cloudinary.com/ provide image resizing on the fly.

Using them you can resize your image very easily by passing the original image, and then the dimensions that you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS (CSS3) to do this.

Use it as background-image:

```
.img {
 background-image: url(path/to/your/ima.ge);
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css according to the size you want.

An example can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/mahima154/x7ejqmeh/

```
img { 
//give the width and height attributes here
}
```